# Getting lane data from OSM

Tags: openstreetmap

I want to extract road network data from OSM for a small city.

From where can I get the [lane information](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key%3alanes) of any road in OSM.

I tried exporting the data in the OSM XML format and there was no lane fields in that file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple answer: If no contributor has uploaded any information regarding lanes of a road, you will find none.

You can off-course look for aerial imagery and add the information yourself. But keep in mind that information from Google sources is not allowed to be uploaded into the OSM database.