# PostgreSQL hstore filter OSM data

Tags: qgis, postgresql, openstreetmap

From the file osm.pbf I created a shape that contains lines of a street network and attributes for `'lanes'`.

Problem: The attribute `'lanes'` is combined with many others in a column `"other_tags"`.

After doing some research, I found that PostgreSQL and the hstore extension can filter individual attributes ([documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/hstore.html)).

I want all OSM IDs and their corresponding values ​​for `"lanes"`.

Now:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
  table
WHERE
  other_tags :: hstore -> 'lanes'
```

comes unknown operator.

Do I still have to set something specific to use hstore?

Comment: does this answer help? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/322889/how-to-get-number-of-lane-from-osm/322896#322896

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried `other_tags::hstore -> 'lanes'` (without spaces) ?

The `::` is to CAST your column in `hstore` format. It is the equivalent to `CAST(other_tags AS hstore)`.

If your field `other_tags` is already in `hstore` format, use `other_tags -> 'lanes'`.

If you want all OSM IDs and the corresponding attribute, create a query like :

```sql
SELECT
  id,
  other_tags::hstore -> 'lanes' AS lanes_value
FROM
  table
;
```

The `WHERE` clause is to filter the results and must return `True` or `False` (boolean).

e.g. :

- `WHERE id < 10`
- `WHERE other_tags::hstore -> 'lanes' = 'bus'`.

Comment: now this error message appears: "ERROR: WHERE argument must have type boolean, not type text
LINE 2: where other_tags :: hstore -> 'lanes'"

Comment: @hugo: see my post edit.

Comment: now this error message appears: 
ERROR:  FEHLER:  Unexpected end of string


SQL state: XX000

It looks something systemic. I'm using pgAdmin 4.

Comment: Can you retry without the spaces around the `::` ?

Comment: unfortunately no change

Comment: It works perfectly fine with psql 10.10.